# What are the odds of rolling a 1 and a 6 in four dice throws?

Tags: probability, dice

There are $\binom42 = 6$ different ways to arrange the two desired rolls in a sequence of $4$ dice, and $6^2$ possible results for the remaining two dice. There are $6^4$ possible total outcomes, so the odds of getting a 1 and a 6 should be $6^3/6^4 = 1/6$, but I get the feeling this is not correct. I think my logic is flawed because I am double-counting some configurations somewhere, but I don't know how to do the computation correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $6^4$ rolls, of which $5^4$ have no $1$'s and $5^4$ have no $6$'s.  However, we've counted the rolls with neither $1$'s nor $6$'s twice.  The probability of both a $1$ and a $6$ is $$\frac{6^4-2\cdot5^4+4^4}{6^4}=\frac{151}{648}\approx.23302469$$

Comment: @Rob This is the solution for the "at least" version of your question.

Answer (score 1):

It should be permutation $P(4,2)=12$, not combination $C(4,2)={4\choose 2}=6$.

Once you fix the two desired dice ($1$ and $6$), there are $4^2$ arrangements for other two dice.

Hence, the probability of one $1$ and one $6$ in four rolls is
$$\frac{12\cdot 4^2}{6^4}=\frac4{27}\approx 0.148.$$

Comment: @Rob This is the solution for the "exactly" version of your question.

Comment: This will work well for exactly two dices with 1 and 6. This does not extend to "at least" two dices with 1 and 6 case because you get duplicates and the below from Saulspatz is the easiest solution for that case.

Comment: @Math Lover, firstly, it is stated "a 1 and a 6", not "any number of 1 and any number of 6", secondly, I don't get duplicates but the other solution does.